# How to grab REST API data and display in a html page

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, api, rest

Hi i am trying to get data from my LMS's rest API and then display it on a html page, I have a URL and an authorization bearer key

I was provided with some examples of how I should show my url and where to place my Authorization key see below

```
GET https://example.thoughtindustries.com/incoming/v2/ping
```

Example Request

```
CURL https://example.thoughtindustries.com/incoming/v2/ping -H 'Authorization: Bearer APIKEY'
```

I get a call back using the CURL in Visual Studio code so i know it can be pulled.

I found this method online which I thought would work

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.apiscience.com/v1/monitors/1572022",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer NN_6xxxxx"
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  $('#monitor_data').append(JSON.stringify(data))
});
```

```html
<h2>Response Data</h2>
<div id="monitor_data">
  <!--location for Javascript to print data-->
</div>
```

I thought this would be the answer when replacing with my own URL and key but nothing happened. Do I need to include the `-H` somewhere and if so what might that look like?

Comment: `-H` is the flag for sending a header in the request, which your jQuery code is doing correctly. I would suggest checking the console for errors when your call is made, and the network tab after making the call to see the response. My guess would be that you're being blocked by CORS, or the bearer token is invalid, assuming the page is structured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy as you have already done this. Write a get ajax call to your API and render your html part from the response you get from the API.

Take a sample example:

```
var getGamePeriod = function(){
            $.ajax({  
                type: "GET",
                url: "yourendpointhere?param=val",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(response){
                    if(response && response.isSuccess){
                      // do your stuffs here..
                    }
                },
                error : function(data,textStatus,errorMessage){
                    alert( textStatus + " " + errorMessage);
                }
            });
        }
```

Of course you need to pass header or auth token if it is required to access the API. Place this method under document.ready method.